# Problems getting desired output from Process.Start()

Tags: c#, command-line

I am working on an application that calls several command line applications to do some post processing on some video files.

Right now I am trying to use [Comskip](http://www.kaashoek.com/comskip/) to identify the commercial breaks in a video recording from my cable card tuner.  This runs just fine, but I am having problems getting the screen output that I need.

```
String stdout = null;

using (var process = new Process())
{
    var start = new ProcessStartInfo(comskip, cmdLine);

    start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    start.CreateNoWindow = true;
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process.StartInfo = start;

    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();

    stdout = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I'm expecting `stdout` to grab what is displayed on the screen the same as when the application is launched manually (screen shot below) which is a continuous feed of what the application is doing, and mixed in the output are lines that give a % progress, which I want to use to update a progress bar

[image: output from commandline]

But running the above code only gives me:

> The commandline used was:
>   "C:\Users\Chris\Google Drive\Tools\ComSkip\comskip.exe" "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ComSkip Tuning Files\Modern Family.wtv" "--ini=C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ComSkip Tuning Files\comskip_ModernFamily.ini"
>
> Setting ini file to C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ComSkip Tuning Files\comskip_ModernFamily.ini as per commandline
>   Using C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\ComSkip Tuning Files\comskip_ModernFamily.ini for initiation values.

I also tried redirecting the `StandardError` stream and grabbing `process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();` but the process appears to hang if I run with these options.

Am I missing something to capture what I'm hoping for, or is it possible that the output stream for this application is going somewhere else that is not accessible?

Comment: `process.WaitForExit()` will not return until the process is done, so if you want to handle this all synchronously, you need to a do a `while (!_process.HastExited) _process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();` to read one line at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set following:

```
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ReadOutput);
     process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorOutput);

     process.Start();
     process.BeginOutputReadLine();
     process.BeginErrorReadLine();
     process.WaitForExit();
```

and catch the output in `ReadOutput` and `ErrorOutput`

```
  private static void ErrorOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Data != null)
     {
        stdout = "Error: " + e.Data;
     }
  }

  private static void ReadOutput(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
  {
     if (e.Data != null)
     {
        stdout = e.Data;
     }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't mention it, but I started with this for `OutputDataReceived` and I switched to the synchronous methods while I tried to figure out which stream contained the data I needed.... but I went back and retried this and also included support for `ErrorDataReceived `... and I found my data.  Not sure why the synchronous methods weren't working, but you did get me to revisit my solution.  Thanks

Comment: @psubsee2003 you are welcome :). I used this code for my project 2 weeks ago and noticed, that some programs showing sometimes normal message as an error and errors as normal messages, maybe bad port from linux which has different return codes...

Answer (score 2):

See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) on `RedirectStandardOutput`. Waiting for the child process to end before reading the output can cause a hang.

It particular, the example says not to do what you have done:

```
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

You should use the events `OutputDataReceived` and possibly `ErrorDataReceived` and update the progress bar in the handler.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on waiting for the process.  The problem the app only appears to hang when I redirect the `StandardError`.  When I am only working with the `StandardOutput`, it does not hang.  And if I move the `StandardError.ReadToEnd()` call before `WaitForExit()`, I still get the same behavior.

Comment: As for the suggestion of using the asynchronous events, I am planning on utilizing them for the progress bar once I am able to determine where the screen output is going.