# Reading output from another running application

Tags: c#, winforms, command, output

I'm working on a custom IDE in C# for a scripting language, and I have a problem.

I'm trying to start the compiler process (pawncc.exe) and pass arguments to it. I've done that, and now I have a problem. When I want to display the output from the compiler application, it only displays some parts of it. It should output this (**got this from the command prompt**):

```
Pawn compiler 3.2.3664                  Copyright (c) 1997-2006, ITB CompuPhase

newGM.pwn(0) : fatal error 100: cannot read from file: "includes/main_include.inc"

Compilation aborted.
1 Error.
```

But it doesn't. It outputs this (**in the application, using the same command/arguments**):

```
Pawn compiler 3.2.3664          Copyright (c) 1997-2006, ITB CompuPhase


1 Error.
```

I just don't get it! It's a really weird thing. It might be something simple but I've been looking at it, and researching for hours now! Here's my code:

```
        public Form3(string path)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this._path = path;

            Process myProcess = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("pawncc.exe");
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.Arguments = path + " -r -d2";
            myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
            myProcess.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                string myString;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
                var ar = myProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 512, null, null);
                ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
                var bytesRead = myProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    myString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                else
                {
                    myProcess.WaitForExit();
                    break;
                }
                richTextBox1.Text = myString;

            }

        }
```

**!!EDIT:**

It does the same thing with this code:

```
        public Form3(string path)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this._path = path;

            Process myProcess = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("pawncc.exe");
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            startInfo.Arguments = path + " -r -d2";
            myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
            myProcess.Start();

            using (StreamReader reader = myProcess.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                richTextBox1.Text = result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I just asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14094771/250725) a couple of days ago.  The short version of the answer is that handling the data events (`myProcess.OutputDataReceived` and `myProcess.ErrorDataReceived `) are far for reliable than using the synchronous read methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to redirect the standard error stream as well:

```
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
```

Edit: I just reviewed the code and discovered that you are only readonly the StandardOutput stream.

I generally monitor the process for both the standard and error output streams using the DataReceived events on the process and adding the results into a stringbuilder, then storing the StringBuilder content in the UI element:

```
    private static System.Text.StringBuilder m_sbText;

    public Form3(string path)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this._path = path;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("pawncc.exe");
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.Arguments = path + " -r -d2";
        myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;

        m_sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(1000);

        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += ProcessDataHandler;
        myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += ProcessDataHandler;

        myProcess.Start();

        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        myProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();

        while (!myProcess.HasExited)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
        }
        RichTextBox1.Text = m_sbText.ToString();
    }

    private static void ProcessDataHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        // Collect the net view command output. 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            // Add the text to the collected output.
            m_sbText.AppendLine(outLine.Data);
        }
    }
```

There are obviously variations on this, but this should get you started.

Comment: @QuinSchurman: I just realized that you were only monitoring the StandardOutput stream. I have updated the answer to show using the process events for receiving the incoming data, which I think is much easier to use.

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked. Marked as answer. Also, thankyou for the quick response.

Comment: So I've used this code - it works nicely, but I would like to expand on this by splitting up the output and sorting them into a list. For example, I could put errors with line numbers into a list in the UI, making the output readable easier.

Better example:
Change this 
`newGM.pwn(0) : fatal error 100: cannot read from file: "includes/main_include.inc"`
to this (In the tab of newGM, a docked list at the bottom.)
`Errors: %i.
error id 100: (FATAL!) file "includes/main_include.inc" is missing or unreadable.`

Comment: There are two calls to `Process.Start`.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed some sporadic issues when dealing with the raw output/error streams from spawned processes in the past, hence why I usually deal with captured output via eventing:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("pawncc.exe");
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.Arguments = path + " -r -d2";
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += OnErrorDataReceived;
myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
myProcess.Start();
myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
myProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why some output is retrieved but not the error.

Comment: @JeremyThompson True, but I've noticed some sporadic issues when dealing with the raw output/error streams from spawned processes (processii?) in the past, hence the suggestion (and the inclusion of the StandardError items)

Comment: +1 fair call, possibly add this in your answer `I've noticed some sporadic issues when dealing with the raw output/error streams from spawned processes in the past, hence my suggestion to hook up the StandardError events.`

Answer (score 1):

I dont have the pawnCC application so I cant try but it appears they restrict the verbosity of debugging information to external applications - apart from the command prompt.

Can you try spawning the pawncc.exe via cmd:

```
"cmd.exe \c CommandParameterToLaunchPawnCCwithArguments"
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, since this would give you "raw" output