# How do I execute a shell script in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have one file which contains a Unix shell script. So now I wanted to 
run the same in .NET. But I am unable to execute the same.

So my point is, is it possible to run the Unix program in .NET? Is there any API like NSTask in Objective-C for running Unix shell scripts so any similar API in .NET?

Comment: I'm assuming that the .net program is running in mono on linux. Right?

Comment: @corey, op wants any api for executing unix shell script in.net??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has been answered before. Just [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234448/run-shell-commands-using-c-sharp-and-get-the-info-into-string).

By the way, you can use:

```
Process proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "program.exe",
        Arguments = "command line arguments to your executable",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

After that start the process and read from it:

```
proc.Start();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // Do something with line
}
```

Comment: This works fine for windows files. Will this work for linux files?

Comment: actually i did not check this on linux ... but in windows it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
        ProcessStartInfo frCreationInf = new ProcessStartInfo();
        frCreationInf.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe";
        frCreationInf.Arguments = "Test.sh";
        frCreationInf.UseShellExecute = false;
        var process = new Process(); 
        process.StartInfo = frCreationInf;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```