# Running CMD commands from C#

Tags: c#, cmd

First of all, I searched a lot to avoid asking a duplicate question. If there is one, I will delete this question immediately.

All the solutions on the web are suggesting to use Process.StartInfo like this one

[How To: Execute command line in C#, get STD OUT results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206323/how-to-execute-command-line-in-c-get-std-out-results)

I don't want to run a batch file, or an .exe.

I just want to run some commands on cmd like

```
msg /server:192.168.2.1 console "foo"
```

or

```
ping 192.168.2.1
```

and return the result if there is one.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Probably duplicate of [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1469790/1617002)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run Command Prompt Commands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, i found an answer

```
while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Komut giriniz.");
                string komut = Console.ReadLine();
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                //startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/C" + komut;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                Console.WriteLine(process.Start());
                string line = "";
                while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = line + System.Environment.NewLine + process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                    // do something with line
                }
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

seems like if you can run cmd.exe with arguments including your command.

thanks for contributing.

Comment: If this is what you wanted to achieve, you should probably have specified in your question that you wanted your application to accept cmd commands from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands are still exe files, you just need to know where they are. For example:

```
c:\windows\system32\msg.exe /server:192.168.2.1 console "foo"
c:\windows\system32\ping.exe 192.168.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way to do this is to use Process.Start. This is demonstrated adequately in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234448/run-shell-commands-using-c-sharp-and-get-the-info-into-string), which is itself a duplicate of two others.

However, as DavidG says, the commands are all exe files and you can run them as such.