# How run node.js application/script from C# console application

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, command-line

I want make tool in c# that allow me execute node.js application/script.
I have following command:

```
node ./bin/3d-tiles-tools.js glbToB3dm -i ./specs/data/CesiumTexturedBox/CesiumTexturedBox.glb -o ./output/CesiumTexturedBox.b3dm
```

I need customize this command because I want give path to folder and automatically run this command for each file in this folder.

**Question:**

How run this command in command line or how to run this js script and pass arguments (give path and names for each file) to this script from C# console application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run shell commands using c# and get the info into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234448/run-shell-commands-using-c-sharp-and-get-the-info-into-string)

Comment: which version of  visual studio you are using?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017 community. 
This linked answer probably will solve my problem but I don't know how construct path.
I have to use "\\" or "/" in C# to make a path? 
Process return me error: "'part of path' is not recognized as an internal or external command..."