# C# How to start .bat File with the normal Behaviour of Windows

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I created this simple .bat File:

```
mstsc C:\Temp\example.rdp
DEL C:\Temp\example.rdp
```

The normal behaviour of the .bat file is to open the rdp dialog and wait til I close the RDP connection. After that the .rdp file will be deleted.

This works perfect for me.

Now I want to open the .bat file from my C# WPF project with a click on a button.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Temp";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k " + "example.bat";
p.Start();
```

I tried all different arguments but the result is always the same the .bat file won't wait for the mstsc command to finish.

Do you have an idea to get this work?

Edit: 
I want the .bat file because i want to delete the .rdp file although my program isn't running and i don't want to close all rdp connections when i close the program.

Comment: Try adding `p.WaitForExit()`.  Though, I'm not sure why that would be needed since presumably you aren't exiting the WPF application.  More likely the process isn't exiting, maybe missing environment variables?  Try hooking into the standard error output to see if there is something there.  Similar to hooking into stdout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234448/run-shell-commands-using-c-sharp-and-get-the-info-into-string/15234481#15234481

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you're seeing when you run this code? It works fine for me in a console application.

Comment: The mstsc command can't be executed because the .rdp file is already deleted by the second command.
There is maybe a problem between a GUI project and a cmd invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not directly running `mstsc`?

```
Process.Start("mstsc", "dir-to-blah.rdp").WaitForExit();
File.Delete("dir-to-blah.rdp");
```

Comment: I want the opportunity to delete the .bat file when my program isn't running. I don't want to close all rdp Sessions when my program is closed.

Comment: I'd suggest writing the rdp file to the TEMP directory and letting windows cleanup handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

try using the "start" command.

`start` is documented here: https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

you should be able to do something like

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Temp";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "start /w" + "/k " + "example.bat";
p.Start();
```

(as usual, my code is completely untested - leaving the final solution up to the OP)

Comment: i already tried start and wait but it didn't worked. The rdp file will be deleted immediately when the bat starts

Comment: That *is* odd ... maybe if you put the "start" in the batch file?

Comment: Hmm... I don't know.  Good luck?  (If you still don't have an answer in 23 hours, message me, and I'll do the work to figure it out)

Comment: Because the OP did.