# Process RedirectStandardOutput empty and DataReceivedEventArgs.Data is null

Tags: c#, .net, process, redirectstandardoutput

When running an application in console mode there are lines written to the console.

Now I want to do this programmatically. Here is some example code that I used: [MSDN on OutputDataReceived Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx)

```
private static StringBuilder _sortOutput = null;

var proc = new Process();
                var info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.FileName = @"C:\SomeApp.exe";

            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            info.CreateNoWindow = false;

            proc.StartInfo = info;

            info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            info.RedirectStandardError = true;

            proc.OutputDataReceived += HandleOutputData;
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += HandleOutputData;

            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

            proc.WaitForExit();

            var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
            var output = _sortOutput.ToString();


    private void HandleOutputData(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        _sortOutput.Append(e.Data);
    }
```

But the DataReceivedEventArgs.Data is always null and I do not get back the result which I can see in the console window that opens.

How can I receive the output? Is there a way to achieve that?

**UPDATE**

I also tried to read the `proc.StandardOutput` directly, but it does not yield any data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's null, because you read the data in `var outPut`

Try following:

a) Change the way you handle it

```
proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(HandleOutputData);
```

b)Comment out the line

```
//var outPut = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that was just something I tried because it was null. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: @MareInfinitus are you sure it's always null? try to skip nulls if (e.Data != null)
     {...

Comment: Yes, it is always null. But I can see strings in the console window if I do not redirect the output. Reminds me of something in batchscripts, where you can redirect 1> and 2>. And I tried to set a new DataReceivedHandler, and it gets also called, but still with null

Comment: @MareInfinitus try combining the question and my answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094771/problems-getting-desired-output-from-process-start/14094822#14094822. Will that work?

Comment: Looks quite the same as what I have at the moment. Can it be something special about the application that I am calling? Can it output to anything else than stdout and I cannot catch it for that reason?

Comment: @MareInfinitus can't imagine something different than stdout if you can see the output on the console.

Comment: Seems to be a different problem! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

As someone else has spotted, there is a bug where `_sortOutput` will be null. But regardless of that, you are completely correct: `e.Data` can and will be null!

In fact, your handler should always get called with `e.Data` equal to null when the AsyncStreamReader that is doing the calling reaches *EOF* of the standard output that is being redirected - which will happen when the process you are running exits. Unless, of course, you deregister your OutputDataReceived event handler first, or cancel asynchronous output redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Null signifies the end of the asynchronous stream.
You must both WaitForExit and wait for the terminating null to come through e.Data